# How to add characters counter on the right bottom corner of the input field in Android Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to add regular input field in my android app with the help of compose.
So I want my input field show on the right side how many characters left that he can add.
For example it starts with 0/100 . Then he starts typing word "hello" and counter shows 5/100

It suppose to be shown INSIDE the input field. Is there a way to achieve that?

Equivalent to app:counterEnabled = "true" as we had in xml

Comment: Have you tried to add a Text() and change that Text value on each input value update ?

Comment: @Rob i need something like app:counterEnabled = "true" as we had in xml

Answer (score 2):

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            JetpackExampleTheme {
                var textValue by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
                CustomTextField(
                    value = textValue,
                    onValueChange = { textValue = it },
                    maxCharacters = 100,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun CustomTextField(
    value: TextFieldValue,
    onValueChange: (TextFieldValue) -> Unit,
    maxCharacters: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    var charCount by remember(value) { mutableStateOf(value.text.length) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {
        TextField(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(50.dp),
            value = value,
            onValueChange = {
                if (it.text.length <= maxCharacters) {
                    onValueChange(it)
                    charCount = it.text.length
                }
            },
        )

        Text(
            text = "$charCount/$maxCharacters",
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(20.dp)
                .wrapContentWidth()
                .align(Alignment.End),
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface.copy(alpha = 0.6f),
            fontSize = 12.sp
        )
    }
}

@Composable
@Preview(showBackground = true)
fun CharCountTextFieldPreview() {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp)
            .height(70.dp)
    ) {
        var textValue by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
        CustomTextField(
            value = textValue,
            onValueChange = { textValue = it },
            maxCharacters = 100,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        )
    }
}
```

for preview add this build.gradle

```
implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
```

Comment: thank you but doesnt it have equvalent to tag app:counterEnabled = "true" as we had in xml?

Comment: **It suppose to be shown INSIDE the input field.** You specifically asked for it this way i did it based on this. Please be clear about what you want. If you want the char count to appear at the bottom, replace `Box` with `Column`.

Comment: Ok thank you. But clarify some moments. 1) Instead of TextField in top of Box I had to use BasicTextField since I had issue "This material API is experimental". 2) @Preview is unresolved reference 3)CustomTextField is unresolved reference 4) Could you please add code calling those functions from mainActivity?

Comment: edited. please check